# Converting a PDF to PNG with the same resolution

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

I am trying to convert a PDF to a PNG using ghostscript and Imagick.

I have tried this:

```
o_imagick = new imagick(mydocu.pdf[0]);
$this->o_imagick->setImageFormat('png');
file_put_contents ("actualpdf.png", $this->o_imagick);
```

Which generates and saves a new image but the resolution is weird. I need it to be the same resolution as the PDF. I assumed it would just generate an exact PNG copy out of the PDF.

Any ideas?

Comment: PDF normally comes in dimensions of A4 paper, so you need to define the resolution/dimensions for PNG image correspondingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF doesn't have a resolution, generally, its a scalable vector format. So your requirement doesn't make sense.

Its possible that the PDF **contains** an image, which can then have a resolution, but that's not quite the same thing.

If you posted an example PDF file we might be able to make some suggestions, but as it is there is not sufficient information.